# Spring batch Remote partitioning | can Master step complete without completion of slave step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have written spring batch remote partitioning approach.I dont want my master step to waits for slave step acknowledgment.I want my master step to complete as soon as it partitions the data.
Is there any configuration for same in spring batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the manager should not wait for workers, what you are describing is not a manager/worker configuration anymore. In a manager/worker setup, the manager divides the work among workers and waits for them to finish (in Spring Batch, you can configure the manager to wait in two different ways: poll the job repository for worker statuses, or gather replies from workers up to a given timeout).

I don't see the rationale behind this "fire-and-forget" approach (who would monitor the status of workers and drive the process accordingly?), but remote partitioning is definitely not suitable to implement this pattern (at least in my opinion). If you really want to (ab)use remote partitioning for that, you can register a custom `PartitionHandler` that does not wait for workers (ie remove [this section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4b9554fcce80e38f7adeffc82a26436199c28191/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/MessageChannelPartitionHandler.java#L231-L236)).